# Call to a member function MsgHTML() on a non-object in php

Tags: php, email

I have been created simple mail sending from localhost using php,

Her is the code:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

EMAIL.PHP:

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');


$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$body ='A sample email';
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mailer->Port = 465;//587;
$mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailer->Username = 'YYYYYYYYYY@gmail.com';
$mailer->Password = 'XXXXXXXXX';
?>
```

when run this code,

following error displayed,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function MsgHTML() on a non-object online 6

note: where is got phpmailer.php source code from this [link](http://phpmailer.worxware.com)

I m new to php, but i want to know, particular this section.

Can anyone help me to fix this,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: $mail is not instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `$mail` is not instantiated, and spelled wrong (did you mean `$mailer`?). Also, you should set `$body` before `MsgHTML($body)`. From your [link](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), you may want to add this

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer;
```

and make changes like so:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer;
$body ='A sample email';

//$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mailer->MsgHTML($body);

$mailer->IsSMTP();
...
```

---

Here is an example of an [HTML-form and PHPMailer](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php):

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

// As this email.php script lives on the same server as our email server
// we are setting the HOST to localhost
$mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication

// When sending email using PHPMailer, you need to send from a valid email address
// In this case, we setup a test email account with the following credentials:
// email: send_from_PHPMailer@bradm.inmotiontesting.com
// pass: password
$mail->Username = "send_from_PHPMailer@bradm.inmotiontesting.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

// $email is the user's email address the specified
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$mail->From = $email;

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress("bradm@inmotiontesting.com", "Brad Markle");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";

// $message is the user's message they typed in
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: You need to complete your code. I added a link of a working example using PHPMailer. Copy and paste that, modify as needed.

Comment: The example I copied and posted into my answer should suffice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we've solved the _"Fatal error: Call to a member function MsgHTML() on a non-object online 6"_ problem. Further questions related to making PHPMailer send emails are off-topic for this thread. Kindly try to make some progress, and post more questions as you go. We need to keep questions on a single topic to be useful for future readers.

Comment: first of all i want to know.. what are the files are required?.